# Test if .blend is running in background

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'd like to know if it was possible to test if my .blend, who is running in background, still open and, if it's possible, how can i do that with python please ?

Answer (score 10):

Blender has a variable you can check for that [`bpy.app.background`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.background)

> Boolean, True when blender is running without a user interface (started with -b)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested and told returned me False when i tried in the console of my active blend after launched another .blend (in background for this one). Did i have to "target" the .blend launched in background ?

Comment: The console you type it into will be the foreground blender that is running a gui. If you start another instance in the background from a script then you want that copy of blender to run a script that tests the background value. Try running `blender --factory-startup -b --python-console` in a terminal then type in `import bpy bpy.app.background`